# vs code, holoviews, hvplot, pyviz [SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' at runCodeHere (... ] [Visual Studio Code]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, holoviews, hvplot, pyviz

Very frustrated*. Code works on jupyter lab, but not in Visual Studio Code.

I’ve created clean new environments, installed, removed, reinstalled [hours gone-by]. i’ve installed as per instructions (in clean environments) [eg., conda install -c pyviz/label/dev holoviews]

here the versions i’m using

```
hvplot.version = ‘0.6.0’
holoviews.version =‘1.13.3’
pd.version = ‘1.0.5’
```

i have the following simple code… from one of your tutorials

'''

```
import hvplot.pandas  # noqa

from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
import hvplot

#%%

flowers.hvplot.plot(x=‘sepal_width’, y=‘sepal_length’, width=600, groupby=‘species’, kind=‘scatter’ )
```

'''

**this is what i managed to capture in a debugger**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘?’
    at runCodeHere (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/vendors~nteract_transforms.bundle.js:2:11588)
    at t.value (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/vendors~nteract_transforms.bundle.js:2:12015)
    at Ta (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:2379474)
    at Pa (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:2382396)
    at vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:2395476
    at Object.t.unstable_runWithPriority (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:25151)
    at Ms (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:2395410)
    at xs (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:2395186)
    at Es (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:2394531)
    at ms (vscode-resource://file///c%3A/Users/cg/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/out/datascience-ui/notebook/commons.initial.bundle.js:2:2393552)
```

**output**

> User belongs to experiment group ‘ShowPlayIcon - start’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘ShowExtensionSurveyPrompt - enabled’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘DebugAdapterFactory - experiment’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘PtvsdWheels37 - experiment’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘UseTerminalToGetActivatedEnvVars -
> control’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘LocalZMQKernel - control’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘CollectLSRequestTiming - control’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘CollectNodeLSRequestTiming -
> experiment’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘EnableIPyWidgets - experiment’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘DeprecatePythonPath - control’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘RunByLine - control’
>
> User belongs to experiment group ‘CustomEditorSupport - control’
>
> conda --version
>
> pyenv root
>
> python3.7
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> python3.6
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> python3
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> python2
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> python
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> py -3.7
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> py -3.6
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> py -3
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> py -2
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import sys;print(sys.executable)”
>
> Python interpreter path: ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
>
> Starting Microsoft Python language server.
>
> ~\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json
>
> ~\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json
>
> ~\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe env list
>
> ~\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import jupyter”
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> -c “import notebook”
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> jupyter kernelspec --version
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> vscode_datascience_helpers.daemon
> --daemon-module=vscode_datascience_helpers.jupyter_daemon -v
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> vscode_datascience_helpers.daemon
> --daemon-module=vscode_datascience_helpers.jupyter_daemon -v
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> vscode_datascience_helpers.daemon
> --daemon-module=vscode_datascience_helpers.jupyter_daemon -v
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon) -m jupyter notebook --no-browser
> --notebook-dir=C:\Users\cg\AppData\Local\Temp\26614261-c8ea-450c-9926-d75a7af2814a
> --config=C:\Users\cg\AppData\Local\Temp\26614261-c8ea-450c-9926-d75a7af2814a\jupyter_notebook_config.py
> --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000.0
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon) -m jupyter kernelspec list --json
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon) -m jupyter kernelspec list --json
>
> ~\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe env list
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon)
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\getJupyterKernels.py
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon)
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\getJupyterKernels.py
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon)
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\getServerInfo.py
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon)
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\getServerInfo.py
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon)
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\getServerInfo.py
>
> ~\Anaconda3\python.exe (daemon)
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\getServerInfo.py
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\normalizeForInterpreter.py
> “import bokeh, holoviews as hv # noqa”
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\normalizeForInterpreter.py
> “import panel as pn”
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\normalizeForInterpreter.py
> “from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers”
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\normalizeForInterpreter.py
> “import hvplot.streamz # noqa”
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\normalizeForInterpreter.py
> “import hvplot.pandas # noqa”
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\viz2\python.exe
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py
> c:\Users\cg.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\normalizeForInterpreter.py
> "flowers.hvplot.bivariate(x=‘sepal_width’, y=‘sepal_length’,
> width=600,
> groupby='species')" ~\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json

Answer (score 0):

From that sample code, I got it to work by doing this:

```
hvplot.plot(flowers, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", width=600, groupby="species", kind="scatter" )
```